# Best way to render OpenCV Mat to Html5 Canvas?

Tags: node.js, html, opencv, html5-canvas, electron

I am using node.js and electron to build a desktop application. I want to use OpenCV with it. I successfully installed opencv4nodejs and now I want cv.Mat to be rendered in HTML5 Canvas. Is it possible to do it directly, or I have to save the image and then render it.

The one more problem is that opencv4nodejs works well in node.js console, but it doesn't work with electron it gives me error:

```
Uncaught Error: The system cannot find message text for message number 0x%1 in the message file for %2. Electron_ASAR.js
\\?\D:\Mohit\Projects\Devide\node_modules\opencv4nodejs\build\Release\opencv4nodejs.node
    at process.module.(anonymous function) [as dlopen] (ELECTRON_ASAR.js:172:20)
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:598:18)
    at Object.module.(anonymous function) [as .node] (ELECTRON_ASAR.js:172:20)
    at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:513:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Mohit\Projects\Devide\node_modules\opencv4nodejs\lib\opencv4nodejs.js:13:8)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Mohit\Projects\Devide\node_modules\opencv4nodejs\lib\opencv4nodejs.js:31:3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible to do so. You probably didn't see the example repo for using opencv4nodejs with electron: [opencv-electron](https://github.com/justadudewhohacks/opencv-electron). Furthermore the steps to render a cv.Mat into a html5 canvas are given in the readme as well.

Regarding your error, you have to run electron-rebuild on native packages. This is also explained in the readme.